# Ruby Error: Array can't be coerced into Fixnum

Tags: ruby

I'm currently working on a simple multiplying method.

CODE:

```
def multiply(*numbers)
    product = 1
    numbers.each{|number|
        product *= number
    }
    return product
end

 puts multiply([2, 3, 4, 5])
```

OUTPUT:

`*': Array can't be coerced into Fixnum (TypeError)
    from calculator.rb:26:in`block in multiply'
    from calculator.rb:24:in `each'
    from calculator.rb:24:in`multiply'
    from calculator.rb:31:in `'

I get this error. It seems the method isn't allowing me to use ".each" on the array.

Also, I want to keep the parameter as *numbers in case it's not an array but two numbers to multiply. I should bring it to your attention that the method works fine when the parameter being passed are two numbers and not an array (i.e. multiply(2, 4)

Answer (score 1):

`multiply` expects an arbitrary number of parameters. You pass only one parameter, which is an array. On the first iteration, `number` is the whole array. Hence the error message.

You have to fix the call, either

```
 multiply(*[2, 3, 4, 5])
```

or, simpler,

```
 multiply(2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is different. In `numbers.each` you iterate over list of arguments, however with `multiply([2, 3, 4, 5])` you are passing one argument, which is an array. The list of arguments is `[[2, 3, 4, 5]]`. So in the only iteration, you are trying to do:

```
1 *= [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

This basically makes no sense to Ruby, so it throws an error.

You should call `multiply` method with a list of arguments, not ona array argument:

multiply(2, 3, 4, 5)

Then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to use array as input, you can use to `flatten` method on the `numbers` array.

```
def multiply(*numbers)
    product = 1
    numbers.flatten.each{|number|
        product *= number
    }
    return product
end

puts multiply([2, 3, 4, 5]) #=> 120
```

The flatten method will take a 2d array and turn into a simple array.

This will also work

```
multiply([2, 3, 4, 5], 2, 2) #=> 480
```

In this case,

```
numbers = [[2, 3, 4, 5], 2, 2]
```

After you apply the flatten method, you get

```
[2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 2]
```

Then you can begin to multiply each number.

As it is normal in Ruby, there is usually a method that do what you are looking to do. In this case, `inject`, and `reduce` can accomplish what you are looking for.

```
def multiply(*numbers)
    numbers.flatten.reduce(&:*)
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Nevermind! I realized that when passing an array using *args, it becomes and array of arrays.